# WAR not getting generated in jdeveloper 11

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application with JSF 2. I am almost done with it and pretty much happy with the outcome, but now comes the problem. I am trying to get the project as a WAR file, but after the WAR creation wizard I am not seeing any WAR file in the mentioned path. Please let me know any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself . We need to use the "Deploy" which comes up when we right click on the Application navigator or in our project